# How to show the current location in a yaml hierarchy

Tags: navigation, filetype-yaml

When working with larger or rather deeply nested yaml files (Hi Rails), it happens quickly that I loose sight of where I am with regards to the indentation hierarchy of the file.

A very simple example to illustrate my point:

```
1| en:
2|   activerecord:
3|     errors:
4|       messages:
5|         parse_error: is syntactically not correct
```

When the cursor is on the line 5, I would like to somehow get the info
`en -> activerecord -> errors -> messages -> parse_error`
via a command or the likes.

Comment: Here's another plugin that does what you are looking for: https://github.com/Einenlum/yaml-revealer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way to do it would be to use an external program if the markup language presents a complex structure or particular edge cases, like the bunch of tools you can find for JSON.

<s>Though YAML seems to be pretty straightforward</s> Even if YAML seems to be [pretty complex](https://arp242.net/weblog/yaml_probably_not_so_great_after_all.html#its-pretty-complex), I started with a one liner working on your snippet to end up with this Vim script you could place in `ftplugin/yaml.vim`:

```
function! YAMLTree()
    let l:list = []
    let l:cur = getcurpos()[1]
    " Retrieve the current line indentation
    let l:indent = indent(l:cur) + 1
    " Loop from the cursor position to the top of the file
    for l:n in reverse(range(1, l:cur))
        let l:i = indent(l:n)
        let l:line = getline(l:n)
        let l:key = substitute(l:line, '^\s*\(\<\w\+\>\):.*', "\\1", '')
        " If the indentation decreased and the pattern matched
        if (l:i < l:indent && l:key !=# l:line)
            let l:list = add(l:list, l:key)
            let l:indent = l:i
        endif
    endfor
    let l:list = reverse(l:list)
    echo join(l:list, ' -> ')
endfunction

nnoremap <F5> :call YAMLTree()<CR>
```

It loops on each line from the cursor to the top looking for a word `\w+` between zero or more spaces `\s*` and a colon `:`, followed by anything. It also checks for indentation to recognize the keys hierarchy.

P.S. My first thought was about indent highlighting plugins like [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) or [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides). That's something  I initially missed on Vim, but I think the heavy slow-down it can cause cured me.

Comment: `YAML seems to be pretty straightforward` -> actually, YAML is a lot more complicated than JSON. The YAML spec is 23,449 words, the JSON spec 1,969 words. It's [one of the problems I wrote about here](https://arp242.net/weblog/yaml_probably_not_so_great_after_all.html). Most Rails files (which the OP mentioned) are limited to a very small part of YAML, so your snippet is probably fine for that, but there are plenty of YAML files out there for which this snippet won't work.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of the variety of syntax in YAML, it should allow basic markdown?! I should have added that the snippet only works on "standard" and properly formatted YAML, and would fail if `\w:` is found earlier in a multi-line block for example. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thanks so much, this works very well for my usecase and is more than fast enough on a 2k line yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the [yaml plugin by Meijvogel](https://github.com/lmeijvogel/vim-yaml-helper) and that has a `YamlDisplayFullPath` function which he recommends putting into autodisplay mode though I prefer it on `InsertLeave` like so:

```
autocmd! InsertLeave *.yml YamlDisplayFullPath
```

Comment: It seems that plugin is currently unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [vim-localorie](https://github.com/airblade/vim-localorie) for this.  It shows you the yaml key of the current line with [`localorie#expand_key()`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-localorie#expand-yaml-key).

(In a Rails view it can also show you translations of the current line's i18n key, although that's not the question here.)